# How to install Google Analytics onto site without internet access

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, google-analytics

I just created an intranet site for the company that I work for. The IT department will not allow my site to access the internet for security reasons, but my boss still wants Google Analytics installed.

I usually just use Joost De Valk's GA plugin, but I don't think it will work since I don't have internet access.

Any ideas about installing GA without an internet connection?

Comment: I think it is quite obvious this won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that GA runs client side in the browser and if your intranet visitors do not have access to GA servers via the internet then GA is not going to work for you.

With that said, [Joost De Valk's GA plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/) has a way to manually enter the UA code rather than using a connection to Google to pull available UA codes.

[image: GA manual enter UA code]

The method shown in the image above will work if the server has no internet access.

If your intranet users don't have internet access and because of this GA is not an option then you can look at using something like [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) instead.

You can install Piwik on the intranet server and use [WP-Piwik](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-piwik/) to bridge Piwik with WordPress

Comment: Wow awesome thanks Brady! So the users do have internet access on their machines. The only thing that doesn't have internet access is the part of the server that the WordPress site is hosted on. Do you think GA will run on that setup?

Comment: I believe it should work that way, because what matters is client side, not server.